# Converting pandas groupby values to numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I **tried multiple solutions** but none of them gives the desired output.

I have a DataFrame:

```
 tag    value
 'A'     3.7
 'A'     1.5
 'E'     9.7
 'E'     2.9
 'B'    -1.2
 'B'     0.8
```

My **expected output** is a Numpy Array:

```
array([[3.7, 1.5],
      [9.7, 2.9],
      [-1.2, 0.8]])
```

I tried using groupby and converting in numpy array

```
df.groupby(['tag']).value.apply(np.array).values
```

But I get output as:

```
array([array([3.7, 1.5]), array([9.7, 2.9]), array([-1.2, 0.8]))], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 2):

If there is always same number of values per groups is possible create nested lists and pass to `np.array`, also for same order of groups add `sort=False` parameter to [`DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) :

```
arr = np.array(df.groupby(['tag'], sort=False).value.apply(list).tolist())
print (arr)
[[ 3.7  1.5]
 [ 9.7  2.9]
 [-1.2  0.8]]
```

Comment: Tried it but it results in an array of the list, for example, array([list([3.7, 1.5]), list([9.7, 2.9]), list([-1.2, 0.8]))] and that's where the normalizer.fit_transform() throws an error.

Comment: @YashGhorpade - With sample data? Or with real data? Because if real data and some groups has 2 or more like 2 values here it is possible.

Comment: With real data. I checked the length of each list within the array, it is same. Still throws this error, ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Comment: One idea `L = df.groupby(['tag'], sort=False).value.apply(list).tolist()` and then `print ([x for x in L if len(x!=2)])` return empty list?

Comment: Yup, it does. It's weird but this hack worked, np.array([i for i in arr]). When I passed this new array to Normalizer, it worked. But there could be some efficient way to it, right?

Comment: @YashGhorpade - One idea, how workin change `np.array` to `np.asarray` ?

Comment: Tried np.asarray still yields array([array([])]). The underlying data structure is really tricky.

Comment: @YashGhorpade - ya, agree. Maybe is good mentioned I test it in pandas 1.0.5, maybe it is also differenc, but no idea.

Comment: No problem, I'll do the for loop thing. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @FlorianBecker - Do you try data from question? - Are same length of each group?

Comment: @jezrael nevermind i'm just stupid. I'm so sorry. I thought value was a field on any dataframe group.

Answer (score -1):

```
df.groupby('tag')['value'].agg(lambda x: x.tolist()).values
```

Comment: This does not create numpy arrays but one numpy array containing lists.

Comment: OP did not ask for numpy arrays but for numpy array.

Comment: Nonetheless, the *expected* output from OP is not an array containing lists but one two-dimensional array (which could be considered one array of multiple arrays).